# Sonar trigger a new analysis?

Tags: eclipse, sonarqube

I have set up a sonar server, and build my project with sonar:sonar.
After I linked it in eclipse. So it is analysed the first time. Everything works and shows up in sonar.

BUT: how can I retrigger an new analysis? Do I have to execute a new sonar:sonar?

ty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

You have to call sonar:sonar everytime you want to execute an analysis that you want to update on the server.

If you have to sonar eclipse plugin ([Sonar IDE](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Sonar+Eclipse)), you can also trigger local analysis, which will not be send to the server.